# Stata multinomial logit IIA assumption violated or not?

Tags: stata, multinomial-logit, hausman, mlogit

My dependent variable is `Choice`, 0 for non-issuers, 1 for seasoned equity issuers, 2 for convertible issuers and 3 for bond issuers. 
I use the following command to run a multinomial logit regression:

```
mlogit Choice CR $ConVar, base(0)
```

To test for IIA assumption, I use the following command:

```
mlogtest, haus
```

The output is below:

[image]

Does this result indicate that IIA is violated?

Then I test the IIA assumption for another multinomial logit regression, in which the dependent variable is `Security` (0 for seasoned equity issuers, 1 for convertible issuers, and 2 for bond issuers).
The Stata commands are below:

```
mlogit Security CR $ConVar, base(0)
mlogtest, haus
```

Output of IIA test is shown below:

[image]

Again, does this mean that the IIA assumption is violated?

Could anyone interpret these two results for me? And I am not sure why some categories of dependent variables have negative chi2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Significant values of chi2 indicate that the IIA assumption has been violated. You can look at the p-values in the 4th column to gauge that.

Some of your test statistics are negative, which is fairly common. [Hausman and McFadden (1984, p. 1226)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1910997) argue that a negative result is evidence that IIA has not been violated.

This logic would suggest that the first one passes, and the second fails.

A good, accessible book with lots of Stata examples and much intuition on this is Long & Freese's [*Regression Models for Categorical Dependent Variables Using Stata*](https://www.stata.com/bookstore/regression-models-categorical-dependent-variables/).

The (partially gated) paper mentioned above is:
Hausman, Jerry, and Daniel McFadden. "Specification Tests for the Multinomial Logit Model." *Econometrica* 52, no. 5 (1984): 1219-240.